# Cross-platform network binary file comparison in C?

Tags: c, networking, file-comparison

Is there an existing library or codebase that is cross platform (Windows/Linux/OSX or a segment thereof) that would allow me to quickly compare the differences between two files over a network?

Basically, trying to recreate a basic version of rsync's "inplace" for a project I'm working on which would take the differences between the files and send just that block level data over the network connection.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [librsync](http://librsync.sourceforge.net/) (with some more information available at [the author's site](http://librsync.sourcefrog.net/)) that you could take a look at. It appears to have been abandoned for quite a while, the last release was in 2004, but it may work well enough as-is.

Comment: Perfect. As a note, I found that this is the same library Drop box uses.